# android setTag method example please

Tags: java, android

Very new to java.  I want to use the setTag method of a view.  It takes an object as a parameter.

In javascript I can create an object at the time I pass it as a parameter,like so:

```
setTag( {id:123} );
```

Can I do something similar in java and if so, how.

I just want to create an anonymous object on the fly.  Can this be done?

Comment: Object creation in Java should be easy to find on Google. I'm sure it's a lot quicker for you to do that than post a question and wait for an answer, unless of course there's something more specific you wanted. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

Comment: Tried googling andcouldn't findan answer - an example would be great

Comment: There's a big difference between Java and Javascript, to the point where I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. If you want to instantiate a new object, you could write `setTag( new Object() )`. However, this is of very limited functionality. It looks like you want to set a field called `id` on the Object. In that case, you'll need to define a new class that extends Object and has an `id` field. Then you'll construct the object, set the id field and then pass it into the `setTag(Object o)` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in java you do setTag( new YourObject(...) );
By the way, 123 is an primitive type and not an object type.
However, you can use the Integer class to create an integer object, new Integer(123);
This might be disturbing from a javascript developer point of view. More info:
[Java Int vs Integer](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.fr/2008/08/java-int-versus-integer.html)

Answer (score 0):

in java 1.7+ at least, not 100% sure about <1.6, you can create it on the fly, but it's quite a bit more verbose that javascript. as PedroCactus mentioned collections can only contain objects in java, but it can/will convert them on the fly. so without further ado:

```
final String id = "some value";
// ...
view.setTag(new HashMap<String, Integer>() {{
    put(id, 123);
}});
```

there's a bit more info about static initializers here [How to create a static Map of String -> Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13445701/how-to-create-a-static-map-of-string-array)