# Shorten if statements with .contains in them

Tags: java, if-statement, java-8

I wanted to ask if there was a different way to go about the if-else boiler-plate situation I am having.

Every single `if` and `else if` has a `string.contains` comparison in them. I am using Java 8.

Is there a way to shorten this using something like `x ? y : z`? Or maybe a switch?

```
if (s.contains("ServerAdmin ")) {
      data.setServerAdmin(s) // This happens everywhere
} else if (s.contains("DocumentRoot")) {
      data.setDocumentRoot(s) // This happens everywhere
} else if (s.contains("ServerName")) {
      data.setServerName(s) // This happens everywhere
} else if (s.contains("ErrorLog")) {
      data.setErrorLog(s) // This happens everywhere
} else if (s.contains("CustomLog")) {
      data.setCustomLog(s) // This happens everywhere
} else if (s.contains("<Directory")) {
      data.setDirectory(s) // This happens everywhere
}
```

Is there a better way to go about this?

~Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If you post more details, that might help. What input are you receiving? Is it possible to apply a grammar and parse the input? Is there a way to properly delimit the input?

Comment: A switch *could* be better, but what kind of logic is going in each statement?

Comment: If the [Apache VirtualHosts](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html) (or something similar) is what you're talking about, you would want to parse this document into a logical structure for a very simple solution.

Comment: Updated the question with logic in them

Comment: This is usually solved with maps or polymorphism.

Comment: If all those properties ```Directory``` .. are limited you would probably like to use an ENUM definition with a switch clause.

Comment: IMO as it is, this is just fine. Unless you know you’re going to change/expand on this in the future.

Comment: When it comes to syntax, there is not too much you can simplify here. You might want to replace s.contains() with your function - but it's rather a matter of taste and the moment I would not do that (following YAGNI principle).

If you wonder how to write it in different way (and not necessarily easier), you might want to use Java 8 and put all the values into HashMap or similar.

Comment: ... if it ain't broken ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Java 8iest solution I can think of is

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
map.put("ServerAdmin", data::setServerAdmin);
map.put("DocumentRoot", data::setDocumentRoot);
// ...
map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(entry -> s.contains(entry.getKey()))
    .findFirst()
    .ifPresent(entry -> entry.getValue().accept(s));
```

Which uses a `LinkedHashMap` to keep the comparison order intact (in case that is relevant), then simply searches for the first `contains` and applies the corresponding function

I guess I would declare the map statically in practice and make the instance of your data class a parameter to save a map creation per execution. Would look like the following for example.

```
private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<Data, String>> MAP = new LinkedHashMap<>();
static {
    MAP.put("ServerAdmin", Data::setServerAdmin);
    MAP.put("DocumentRoot", Data::setDocumentRoot);
    // ...
}
public void foo(Data data, String s) {
    MAP.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(entry -> s.contains(entry.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(entry -> entry.getValue().accept(data, s));
}
```

Comment: @Ellisan well if you are OK going on this route, this could probably be simpler https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242561/1059372

Answer (score 2):

You can create a set of magic strings and their corresponding actions, then iterate over those, instead of duplicating a large `if-elseif-else` block.

```
private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<YourObj, String>> configActions;

static {
    Map<String, BiConsumer<YourObj, String>> tmp = new HashMap<>();
    tmp.put("ServerAdmin", YourObj::setServerAdmin);
    tmp.put("DocumentRoot", YourObj::setDocumentRoot);
    // ...
    configActions = Collections.unmodifiableMap(tmp);
}

public static YourObj load(List<String> directives) {
    YourObj config = new YourObj();
    directives.forEach(dir -> set(config, configActions, dir));
    return config;
}

static <T> void set(T obj, Map<String, BiConsumer<T, String>> setters, String value) {
    setters.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> value.contains(e.getKey()))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(e -> e.getValue().accept(obj, value));
}
```

In general, looking for a magic string with `contains()` is not a very robust way to control logic. If the string `s` follows some format that ensures that your search won't result in false positives, consider parsing that format, and extracting the token. And if the input strings don't follow any strict format, you have a high chance of landing on the wrong token first. For example, if your configuration is stored in a YAML, XML, or JSON file, use a YAML, XML, or JSON parser, respectively.

As an example, consider what happens if you had tokens "LogFile" and "LogFileEncoding". Both `contain()` "LogFile", but only one is a correct match.

If you are using Java 9 or later, you can initialize your `Map` like this:

```
private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<YourObj, String>> configActions = Map.of(
  "ServerAdmin", YourObj::setServerAdmin,
  "DocumentRoot", YourObj::setDocumentRoot,
  // ... 
);
```

If you have more than ten entries, you can use the `entry()` builder:

```
private static final Map<String, BiConsumer<YourObj, String>> configActions = Map.ofEntries(
  Map.entry("ServerAdmin", YourObj::setServerAdmin),
  Map.entry("DocumentRoot", YourObj::setDocumentRoot),
  // ...
);
```

These [methods were added](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) to address the lack of collection literals, and avoid the problems with existing workarounds.

Comment: Did you know you can declare, initialize and populate an unmodifiable map in one line? If you want me to edit it in (I believe it’d be clearer and simpler, plus I dislike static blocks), let me know.

Comment: @Bohemian Do you have a link to an example of your approach?

Comment: Here's [one I prepared earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13446515/256196)! Enjoy :)

Comment: @bohemian That’s what I thought. There are several technical drawbacks to anonymous instance initializers, and they don’t improve legibility.

Comment: Technical drawbacks? Name a few, or even one. I'm not aware of any for `static` instances. Depending on the use case, they can *improve* legibility, especially if you need/use a helper method to make entry creation more intuitive. At least you avoid the trainwreck of using a `tmp` variable that adds no value whatsoever (but does add clutter).

Comment: @Bohemian the fact that the double curly brace anti-pattern unnecessarily creates a subclass behind the scenes, is only a small disadvantage, granted, but put it in relation to the absence of any advantage. You call it “one line”, but it is still the same number of lines as before, at least with any reasonable formatting (even in your answer). It’s not “clearer and simpler” as it is obfuscating what is really going on, like creating that anonymous subclass and, of course, still having a “static block” that will create the instance of the anonymous class and assign it to the `static` field.

Comment: @Bohemian Double-brace initialization obscures what's really happening. While using an extra variable does add clutter, and also opens the door to let the underlying collection escape, it is an honest and explicit representation of what's happening. The most serious flaws of double-brace initialization don't apply here, but it would be irresponsible to make use of it in this example without explaining its caveats, and that would distract from the main point, which is the use of a map. Usage of the Java 9 is more readable *and* provides a *much* better implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky. But try if it if you feel better:

```
public class Data {
   private static Map<String, BiConsumer<Data, String>> SETTER_MAP = new LinkedHashMap<>(); // Use LinkedHashMap if you want to check the contains in order
   static {
       SETTER_MAP.put("ServerAdmin ", Data::setServerAdmin);
       ... your list goes on...
   }

   public void String setData(String s) {
     SETTER_MAP.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> s.contains(e.getKey())
                    .findFirst().ifPresent(e -> e.getValue().accept(this, s);
   }

}
```

Comment: if you are iterating the map, way not put a `Predicate` as they key than? like this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242561/1059372

Answer (score 1):

Probably in order to press the point on how Java-8 simplifies java coding, here is my take on the Command pattern OO based approach to this problem:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute(Data data, String containerString);
}

public abstract class AbstractCommand implements Command {

  protected  String containeeString;
  protected AbstractBoundAction(String containeeString) {
    this.containeeString = containeeString;
  }

  protected abstract void action(Data data, String containerString);

  public void execute(Data data, String containerString) {
    if(containerString.contains(containeeString)) {
       action(data,containerString);
    }
  }
}
public class ServerAdminCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  public ServerAdminCommand() {
     super("ServerAdmin ");
  }

  protected void action(Data data, String containerString) {
     data.setServerAdmin(containerString);
  } 
}
public class DocumentRootCommand extends AbstractCommand {
  public DocumentRootCommand() {
     super("DocumentRoot");
  }

  protected void action(Data data, String containerString) {
     data.setDocumentRoot(containerString);
  } 
}
// And so on for the remaining data method invocation per contained strings
```

And the usage of all this boilerplate code :

```
String containerString = ....;
Data data = .....;
....
....
List<Command> commands = Arrays.asList(new ServerAdminCommand() , 
                         new DocumentRootCommand() /* etc...... */ );
commands.forEach(com -> com.execute(data,containerString));
```

Comment: Do you mean, "Let me show you how bad this would look without Java 8 and lambdas?"

Comment: @erickson : pretty much. I want to use this as an example to some colleges who insist on working without the benefits of Java-8.

Comment: Okay, I like it then!

Comment: I really liked it, but 1+1+6 classes are too many for such a tiny snippet

Comment: @Andrew : Exactly. This is a show case of how functional programming trumps over OO implementations.

Comment: @Andrew you could hide all this complexity behind an `enum`, I am sure you have already seen this before... https://stackoverflow.com/a/50242561/1059372

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a field to whatever `s` is, and creating an `enum` listing out the possible cases: contains ServerAdmin, contains DocumentRoot, etc. Call this `enum` field of `s` `messageType` for our purposes:

```
switch (s.messageType){
    case SERVER_ADMIN: data.setServerAdmin(s); break;
    case DOCUMENT_ROOT: data.setDocumentRoot(s); break;
    ...
}
```

It's shorter, but maintains readability and intuitiveness.

UPDATE: just saw that `s` is a `String`. Unless it's useful to make `s` an object of your own design for other reasons, it's probably not worthwhile to wrap it just to add an `enum` (I wouldn't even extend `String`), so I would recommend sticking to the `if`s.

Comment: I'll add: map or stream hacks make it much shorter (albeit you might have to set up a complicated data structure), but not more efficient. They also lose a lot of the *readability*. Unless you *need* a map or stream hack for other reasons, IMO it's better to leave your code clear and readable than to minimize number of lines